# WPF DepenencyProperty logic in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

Currently my CustomControl adjust his element color affectionate of the status received from the PLC. The CustomControl haves two dependency property: Statebrush and InstanceAdresFFU. As you can see, the InstanceAdres has the same starting adres as the StateBrush adres.

**MainView1.xaml**

```
<cc:CustomControl1 x:Name="FFU_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" Margin="96,243,0,0" Width="44" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" 
            StateBrush="{vw:VariableBinding VariableName=MCS1.Cleanroom.SIM_Cleanroom.SIM_FFUControl2.Observers.oStatus, Converter={StaticResource ValueToStateBrushConverter}, States={StaticResource BrushListState}, StateMode=Value}"
            InstanceAdresFFU="MCS1.Cleanroom.SIM_Cleanroom.SIM_FFUControl2"/>
```

Therefore I want to get rid of the StateBrush binding in the MainView.

```
<cc:CustomControl1 x:Name="FFU_2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" Margin="96,243,0,0" Width="44" Height="30" BorderThickness="1" 
            InstanceAdresFFU="MCS1.Cleanroom.SIM_Cleanroom.SIM_FFUControl2"/>
```

And in the code behind, something like this:

```
StateBrush= this.InstanceAdresFFU + ".Observers.oStatus", Converter={StaticResource ValueToStateBrushConverter}, States={StaticResource BrushListState}, StateMode=Value}"
```

So my question is, is it possible (and how) to add a default variable to a depency property in the backhand, with its associated Converter={StaticResource ValueToStateBrushConverter}, States={StaticResource BrushListState}, StateMode=Value}"

**CustomControl1.cs**

```
namespace HMI.CustomControl
{

 public class CustomControl1 : System.Windows.Controls.Button
 {
   public Brush StateBrush
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(StateBrushProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StateBrushProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StateBrush.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StateBrushProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StateBrush), typeof(Brush), typeof(CustomControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));

   public string InstanceAdresFFU
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(InstanceAdresFFUyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InstanceAdresFFUyProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InstanceAdresFFU.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty InstanceAdresFFUyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InstanceAdresFFU", typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl1), new PropertyMetadata(""));
    }
  
}
```

**Generic.xaml** : Frontend of object

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:HMI.CustomControl" xmlns:vw="http://inosoft.com/visiwin7">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type cc:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cc:CustomControl1}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="19*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               
                            <vw:Label Margin="5" Text="{TemplateBinding LabelText}" Height="40" Focusable="False"/>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding StateBrush}" Width="40" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1,1,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"/>
                                <Line Stroke="#FF000000" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1,4,0,0" Width="40" Y1="0" Y2="0.114682539682633" X2="39.5" StrokeThickness=".5" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"/>
                                <Line Stroke="#FF000000" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1,1,-2,0" Width="43" Y1="0" Y2="0.114682539682633" X2="39.5" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"/>
                            </Grid>
                  
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: this.InstanceAdresFFU is the default value that is accessible in the CustomControl class

Comment: `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` needs some sort of static value to initialize the property.  So take the logic that lives in your `ValueToStateBrushConverter.Convert` function and put it into some sort of static function somewhere.  Make your control initialize some sort of static member with a call to that static function.  Then make the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` use the static member at initialization.  If the converter needs some sort of value that you'll only know at runtime, it won't work

Comment: Besides a static default value in the property metadata, you may of course also set an intial property value in the control's constructor, typically by calling `SetCurrentValue(StateBrushProperty, ...);`

Comment: It would be helpful  to understand what VariableBinding is, a custom MarkupExtension? And where are the referenced resources defined?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of valuable information I will show you some very general examples to give you an idea.

You must register a property change callback and handle the `InstanceAdresFFU` value and the `ValueBinding` markup extension.
The example assumes that the referenced resources are defined in the *App.xaml* resources.

**If `VariableBinding` extends `BindingBase`**

```cs
public class CustomControl1 : Button
{
  public string InstanceAdresFFU
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(InstanceAdresFFUyProperty); 
    set => SetValue(InstanceAdresFFUyProperty, value); 
  }

  // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InstanceAdresFFU.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
  public static readonly DependencyProperty InstanceAdresFFUyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "InstanceAdresFFU", 
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(CustomControl1), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged));

  private static void OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => (d as CustomControl1).OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged();
  
  public MultiSelectComboBox() => this.Loaded += OnLoaded;

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged();

  protected virtual void OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged()
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.InstanceAdresFFU))
    {
      return;
    }

    IValueConverter converter = (IValueConverter)Application.Current.Resources["ValueToStateBrushConverter"];
    object states = Application.Current.Resources["BrushListState"];
    var binding = new VariableBinding
    {
      VariableName = $"{this.InstanceAdresFFU}.Observers.oStatus",
      Converter = converter,
      States = states,
      StateMode = "Value"
    }
     
    SetBinding(StateBrushProperty, binding);
  }
}
```

**If `VariableBinding` does not extend `BindingBase`**

```cs
public class CustomControl1 : Button
{
  public string InstanceAdresFFU
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(InstanceAdresFFUyProperty); 
    set => SetValue(InstanceAdresFFUyProperty, value); 
  }

  // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InstanceAdresFFU.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
  public static readonly DependencyProperty InstanceAdresFFUyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "InstanceAdresFFU", 
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(CustomControl1), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged));

  private static void OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => (d as CustomControl1).OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged();
  
  public MultiSelectComboBox() => this.Loaded += OnLoaded;

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged();

  protected virtual void OnInstanceAdresFFUChanged()
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.InstanceAdresFFU))
    {
      return;
    }

    IValueConverter converter = (IValueConverter)Application.Current.Resources["ValueToStateBrushConverter"];BrushListState
    object states = Application.Current.Resources["BrushListState"];
    var markupExtension = new VariableBinding
    {
      VariableName = $"{this.InstanceAdresFFU}.Observers.oStatus",
      Converter = converter,
      States = states,
      StateMode = "Value"
    }
     
    this.StateBrush = markupExtension.ProvideValue(new ServiceProviders());
  }
}
```